# How to prevent overfitting when encoding categorical variables

Tags: classification, categorical-data, predictive-models, overfitting

Currently, I am working on a binary classification project that include both numeric and categorical variables as predictors. I recently read an article about encoding variable with weight of evidence in `R` -  http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-credit-scoring-woe-information-value-in-woe-package/. I encoded my categorical variables and also two way interactions of the categorical variables with weight of evidence. I used a 10-fold cross validation and the encoding performed really well on my training set but dismal on my test set. The model was really overfit.

My question is -

1. When doing such encodings what is the best practice to get the good performance of such transformations while reducing overfitting?

**Note:**
My training set has about 114k records and I am using `xgboost` as my classification algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid overfitting while using WOE transformations, you should use 'penalty' to discard transformed features that don't hold up against the validation set. Check out the 'information' package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Information/Information.pdf

Also, here's a more elaborate explanation and demonstration of how 'penalty' should be used: http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/08/13/weight-of-evidence/